# How can I restart my iphone app from an AlertView?

Tags: iphone

I want to restart my application by alert ok button click. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is; you can't if you want to get your app approved by Apple.

The longer answer is to first show your alert:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
            initWithTitle: @"Restart"
            message: @"Click to restart the application"
            delegate: self
            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
            otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

And make sure that your view-controller is set up to detect when the user clicks the "OK" button:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
        //do stuff here...
}
```

And then replace `//do stuff here...` with code to make your application *appear* that it is restarting.  You cannot actually programmatically restart your application (you can quit programmatically by calling `exit()`, but forcing the app to restart after that is not possible), the best you can do is run some effects to make the user think that that's what happened.  How to do that will depend upon what your app looks like/does when it starts up.

Comment: Let me tell you what i want to do.I have a quiz app.At the ending i am showing a skill level with the alertView.Now i want to restart the game by loading the tableView with a new quesiton.Everything is working fine.Just tell me how can i reload my tableView with new Question by releasing the QuesitonObject.

Comment: @sohel14_cse_ju - I assume you've tried assigning the new `Question` to whatever property or `DataSource` you are using to generate content for your `UITableView`?  Because if you do that, in theory all you should need to do is call `[tableView reloadData]` to refresh the view with the new data.

Comment: i have a dictionary from where i am loading my CustomTableView Cell.The tbaleView property is set as tableView.And i loaded the cell from another xib file.after the cencel button click i am doing this.[dicitonary release];[self.tableView reloadData];but it's not changing the tableview last instance.It's loading from the last quesiton.

Comment: If you release the dictionary then there is no data to reload, right?  Wouldn't this just require you to load new questions into your dictionary for it to render?

Answer (score 2):

You can exit the application via exit(0), and then call a URL which is made in .plist file,  and restart your app.

To make the URL, add a row with "URL types", Item 0 is der, In item0 "URL identifier", in url identifier, write "com.provisionalprofiel.AppName", then add URL Shemes in item0, in it insert write "AppName" which you define in URL identifier.

Finally call the url with "AppName:/", and see the magic!

Comment: +1 Well done on posting an answer with a possible solution! I'm not familiar with the subject, so I can't really edit the answer properly, since it seems like a real gem of information. Thanks, and good luck on Stack Overflow!

Comment: One question comes to mind.  How do you call `exit(0)` and _then_ "call a URL" (or do anything else programmatically) after the call to `exit(0)`?  That seems like it wouldn't be possible.

Comment: We can directly call the url with some dalay, so when url is called then app is automatically restarted. So we dont need to exit(0).

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

(You can only exit your application)